# Observable array mobx doesn't update when the array starting empty

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobx

I have an empty observable array (that will containing object with key 'id' and 'val') in my store (let say myStore)

```
@observable 
var myArray = [];
```

then I have a function in myStore

```
@action
addItem(item){ //item = { id : 'id1' , val : 123}
   myArray.push(item);
}

@computed
get getmyArray{
   return myArray;
}
```

Now the problem is, when I push item to myArray, my component that Observe myArray **doesn't re-render**. So, I want to render each element from myArray. Like this

```
renderList = () => {
    const store = this.props.myStore;

    var list = [];

    for(var index in store.getmyArray){
        list.push(
                <li key = {store.getmyArray[index].id}>
                    {store.getmyArray[index].id + " ===> " + store.getmyArray[index].val} 
                </li> 
        );  
    }

    return (
        <ul className = "curr-list">
            {list}
        </ul>
    );

}
```

And the thing is, those codes were running just fine if I have some initial elements when I declare myArray, but it won't re-render again if I delete all the elements from myArray, then push some item again to it.

So,

1. My component doesn't re-render when myArray empty, then push an item to it. (When I console.log(myArray), the item is there in myArray, my component just doesn't re-render )
2. My component doesn't re-render when myArray have some initial elements, then I delete all elements, then I push again to myArray (when I delete and add element to myArray, as long as it's not empty, my component re-render just fine).

Any clue why ?

Comment: How are you deleting all the elements in the array?

Comment: I don't delete all the elements at once, I have a button in the li tag that will handle the element that want to be deleted. So, I delete it one by one.

Comment: Alright. Could you include that code in the question? Ideally, create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in e.g. [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new) and it will be easier to help you.

Comment: Here is my code https://codesandbox.io/s/2wjyjzw51p . In myComponent.tsx and myStore.ts. I'm not sure it will run on the sandbox though. Basically its a simple app  where you can see a list of Foreign Exchange Rates. I'm sorry, I couldn't give a perfect example

Comment: Try to make it runnable with as little code needed as possible to reproduce your bug. Your `handleDelete` and `addToListCurr` look at bit odd. [You could try this](https://codesandbox.io/s/llq6k2jz1z).

Comment: Please check here https://codesandbox.io/s/7k745kp2vx . As you can see here, myNumber is re-rendering , but not the element in renderList(). You can see the console too, and myArray is updating.

Comment: Alright, I've found the solution for my problem, it seems that I have to deep copy myArray so the mobx can notice the change to my empty array. I deep copy my array using like this :

`@action
addItem(item){
   let temp = [];
   temp.push(item);
   this.myArray = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(temp));
}`

But, I still wonder though why my code before working on array with element, but not when the array started empty. I'm assuming it involve reference to array in JavaScript and the way mobx notice change to that reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure too deep copy the array (or object) when handling observable array or object